# Network fails with docking dongle

Tags: networking, docking

I've run into a very strange problem. I'm happily browsing along in Firefox when tabs become unresponsive. Typically the state is induced by loading a tab. When I attempt to do so, the loader icon in the tab spins and spins but doesn't work otherwise. If I go to another tab and F5 it I get the same behavior. If I try to close the browser I can't. If I kill the process via terminal, various of the Firefox processes close but other become defunct. That result is the same whether I kill or kill -9... for whatever reason, Firefox gets into a state where it can't be cleared from the process table. The usual response is to kill its parent process, but that's PID 1. It's the same in Chrome.  Also, I can't reboot the system in this state. I have to power down with the hardware switch and turn it back on.  Also, ifconfig will no longer run... it just sits there, no output, unresponsive to Ctrl-C.

On a hunch I disconnected my docking dongle. It's not a full docking station, just a little 2"x2" Thunderbolt guy with Ethernet, HDMI, VGA, and USB. When I rebooted I found that Firefox worked just fine with only the keyboard connected via USB. I've also found that Windows 10, dual-booted on the same machine, works with no problems at all so far with the dongle connected.

So, I checked dmesg.  I ran it in tail mode (dmesg -wT), started looping the timestamped output from ifconfig every 15 seconds, and waited a little without the dongle plugged in.  Then I plugged in the dongle.  After a few minutes ifconfig stopped responding.  At the same time, the following were reported by dmesg:

```
[Tue Dec 10 10:06:18 2019] usb 4-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[Tue Dec 10 10:06:18 2019] usb 4-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[Tue Dec 10 10:06:18 2019] usb 4-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[Tue Dec 10 10:06:18 2019] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 enxd481d738f3a0: Using pass-thru MAC addr d4:81:d7:38:f3:a0
```

So... any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? I've gathered the information I can think of, but otherwise I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
System: Dell Precision 5510
```